# How to make a Wordpress Mobile/Responsive Menu work

Tags: javascript, wordpress

I have recently started to make my own WordPress theme for my own site. However, I'm not using a framework like bootstrap. Starting from the smallest viewport, I am creating the responsive menu. I want to create a slide-in menu. I am not that familiar with Javascript so I only got my menu to open, but I cannot close it when I click outside the menu or on the button. Also, I have noticed my menu items(the links) are not in the order I put them in the Wordpress backend under the Menus tab.

I would really like someone to help me fix my menu and make it close or any help with a better idea or code structure to make the menu function. Also please an answer on the order of the menu not working if possible. Thank you.

Here is a link to the code I adjusted to work on WordPress https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_sidenav.asp

**My header.php code to show the menu**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
```

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<title>EGlobe</title>
<?php wp_head(); ?>
</head>
<body>
<div class="menu-button-holder"><span class="hamburger" style="font-size:30px;cursor:pointer" >&#9776;</span></div>



<?php

wp_nav_menu(
  array(
    'theme_location' => 'Header Menu',
    'menu_class' => 'header-menu',
    'menu_id' => 'header-menu'


  ) 
);
```

**functions.php where I register the menus**

```
//registering  the menu support for the site
function register_my_menus() {

    register_nav_menus(
    array(
      'header-menu' => __( 'Header Menu' ),
      'footer-menu' => __( 'Footer Menu' )
     )
   );
 }
 add_action( 'init', 'register_my_menus' );
```

**CSS for the styling like in the link**

```
.header-menu .page_item{
    list-style-type: none;
}

.hamburger{
    display:none;
}

@media screen and (max-width:320px){



    .menu-button-holder{
        position: fixed;
        width:90%;
    }   

    .hamburger{
        display:block;
        float: right;
        z-index: 1;
        top:0;
        margin-bottom: 20px;



    }

    .header-menu{
        height: 100%;
        width:0;
        background-color: black;
        position: fixed;
        z-index: 1;
        top: 0;
        left: 0;
        padding-top: 60px;
        transition: 0.5s;
        overflow-x: hidden;

    }

    .header-menu a{
        padding: 8px 32px 8px 32px;
        text-decoration: none;
        font-size:20px;
        color: #fff;
        display: block;

    }

    .header-menu a:hover{
        color: #868686;
    }


}
```

**And the javascript I used to open the menu. But the close function does not work**

```
document.addEventListener("click", openNav);

function openNav() {
    document.getElementById("header-menu").style.width = "250px";
}



if(document.getElementById("header-menu").style.width = "250px"){

    document.addEventListener("click", closeNav);

    function closeNav(){

        document.getElementById("header-menu").style.width = "0px";
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Change this one line

```
if(document.getElementById("header-menu").style.width = "250px")
```

to this

```
if(document.getElementById("header-menu").style.width == "250px")
```

Comment: Hi @Ruslan. Thanks for the reply. Unfortunately I have tested this, but it doesn't work either. Here is the error I see in Chrome inspect - Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'style' of null
    at responsive-menu.js?ver=1:10 (responsive-menu.js is the js file where the script is in)

Comment: Hi @Feyt Do you have a link or could you past your code to https://jsfiddle.net ?

Comment: I can create a Codepen but it depends what you want to test? Should I paste all the code above in? And wouldn't this mean that the PHP from WordPress won't work anymore?

Comment: Can you past css, html and js only?

Comment: The classes and id gets created by WP php functions. Here is rather a link to the files https://github.com/FullNoob/Theme-Files101

Answer (score 0):

You can use like this one

```js
document.getElementById("hamburger").onclick = function(){
  if(document.getElementById("header-menu").style.width == "250px"){
 document.getElementById("header-menu").style.width = "0px";
  } else {
 document.getElementById("header-menu").style.width = "250px";
  }
};
```

```css
.header-menu .page_item{
    list-style-type: none;
}

.hamburger{
    display:none;
}
    
   
    
    .menu-button-holder{
        position: fixed;
        width:90%;
    }   
    
    .hamburger{
        display:block;
        float: right;
        z-index: 1;
        top:0;
        margin-bottom: 20px;
        
        
      
    }
    
    #header-menu{
        height: 100%;
        width:0;
        background-color: black;
        position: fixed;
        z-index: 1;
        top: 0;
        left: 0;
        padding-top: 60px;
        transition: 0.5s;
        overflow-x: hidden;
        background: red;
        
    }
    
    .header-menu a{
        padding: 8px 32px 8px 32px;
        text-decoration: none;
        font-size:20px;
        color: #fff;
        display: block;
    
    }
    
    .header-menu a:hover{
        color: #868686;
    }
```

```html
<div class="menu-button-holder">
<span  class="hamburger" id="hamburger" style="font-size:30px;cursor:pointer" >&#9776;</span>
</div>

<div id="header-menu">Menu content</div>
```

Comment: this does work in plain html, css and js yes. But making it work on WordPress with the php in the dynamic menu content is difficult. I still get an error - Cannot set property 'onclick' of null
    at responsive-menu.js?ver=1:21